# Is temporal logic outside set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Mathematics (or a version of it) can be built up from set theory.

Could temporal logic also be built from set theory? Or is it something outside of it?

Because to my mind, mathematics is about things that are always true. But on the other hand you can use mathematics to talk about time and space.

So my question is, is set theory enough to talk about time?

e.g. a statement like "If John has three apples today, he may have two oranges tomorrow."

I can think of the set of things John has. Maybe the set of days. And other sets.

Comment: You do not even need set theory to set up [temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Prior's_tense_logic_(TL)), adding some symbols for tenses to the ordinary predicate calculus is enough.

Comment: Why is this voted close? Is my question too stupid?

Comment: @zooby No, it is a good question. +1

Comment: The "may have" is problematic. Your statement gives us no new information about the world that could be tested. You could, however, formalize "If John has three apples today, he WILL have two oranges tomorrow." If you want to convey the passage of time from day $0$ (today) to day $1$ (tomorrow), you  could define functions $f$ and $g$ on $N$ such $f(n)$ is the number of apples he has on day $n$, and $g(n)$ is the number of oranges he has on day $n$. Then you might translate the revised sentence as $f(0)=3 \implies g(1)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Long comment*

[Temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Prior's_tense_logic_(TL)) is a branch of formal logic.

You cam develop it with the standard "jargon" of mathematical logic.

In order to formalize its syntax and its semantics, as per any other branch of mathematical logic, you can use the language and the tools of set theory (a very weak part of it).

In this scenario, we are using the *universal language* of set theory to describe in a precise way the mathematical object : "logic of time", in the same way that we can use the language of set theory to develop geometry : the "logic of space".

Is this the sense of "built up" you are referring to ?

There is another sense of "foundation" that we usually use with regards to set theory and mathematics : set theory can be used to *define* in terms of sets only (i.e. using the relation : $\in$) suitable "proxies" for the basic mathematical objects, e.g. number, and derive from set theory axioms the relevant axioms, e.g. Peano's axioms.

Thus, the second issue is : is it possible (and make it sense) to define in set theory terms only the basic objects of time logic and the relvant axioms ?